# For BIBO stability, the poles cannot lie on imaginary axis?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Is this a true statement:

"for BIBO stability, the poles cannot lie on imaginary axis" because in that case we can excite the circuit with a bounded sinusoidal [that could match the resonant frequency of the cicuit]"

[image: fig 1]

This one has me a little bit confused because they just finished explaining that all poles in the left half of s-plane is stable.

Now they throw in a rule that you can't use the imaginary axis if you want stability?  I don't know... it smells wrong to me...

Comment: Being on the imaginary axis is not being on the left-half of the s-plane. It's being in the center of the left and right halves. And who says you can't use the imaginary axis? You can still have imaginary components. Your real component just can't be zero or positive. Your real component must be <0, in other words, in must be in the left half of the s-plane. It's all saying the same thing.

Comment: @pico sorry to point this out, but, if you don't trust that book (and your other questions validate your disbelieve in it). Shouldn't you try different materials or even Wikipedia/EESE older posts?

Comment: @DKNguyen that's a  good point, imaginary axis means Real component = 0 between Right half plane an left half plane...

Comment: Or better yet **experiment with the math**.  Take a system with transfer function \$H(s) = \omega_0 / (s^2 + \omega_0^2)\$.  Excite it with a sine wave \$x = \cos \omega_0 t\$ and *see for yourself* what happens.

Comment: @jDAWQ ....I kind of like that its a messed up book... it gives me something to do...

Comment: for some reason, when they said imaginary, i was thinking imaginary component and  didn't see the word axis after the word instead... probably because they put an "omega" character between imaginary and axis as a distraction... because \omega isn't really an axis...its a radial direction.

Comment: They're taking the left hand plane as being open to the right, with the imaginary axis being a boundary, but not part of the plane.  If you don't know the stuff, and you don't understand what you're reading, why do you assume that it's the books *author* who's wrong?

Comment: Re-reading, they say "if the poles lie **in** the left hand plane".  As in "**inside** the left hand plane".  Not on the boundary, and thus not at a point where \$\mathcal{Im}(s) = 0\$.

Comment: @pico, well, if you like that learning method you could at least look it up elsewhere before posting it here, you seem to be doing zero research in this question and you still have more 40 pgs of this _book_ . Be considerate with other people's time...

Comment: @TimWescott he assumes the book is wrong because the author put very little effort while typing https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478176/is-possible-for-a-series-rlc-circuit-to-be-unstable-if-it-doesnt-have-any-volta/478190?noredirect=1#comment1214101_478190

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Systems stability with zero poles](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/201416/systems-stability-with-zero-poles)

Comment: @jDAQ, chill out... all i'm doing is generating traffic for this website by asking a common question that people search for on the internet..  if it you don't want to waste your time on the question, then don't answer then it will just get deleted eventually because nobody answered it..

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true and there is no contradiction between these two definitions of stability.

The s-plane is a representation of:
$$s=\sigma + j\cdot\omega$$

The left half of the s-plane mean $$\sigma<0$$

The imaginary axis is given by $$\sigma = 0$$ because in that case all you have is

$$s= j\cdot\omega$$